# Change color inside the DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar

I use a **DatePicker** for my application. I can change all the values I need. The last value that I need is the color of the month and year (here in blue). As well as the background color (here in light blue).

Can someone give me an example or tip on how to change the color to red? The DatePicker consists of several components like e.g. Calender. Via my CustomStyle I could not find a suitable entry so far.

[image]

Comment: This may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Calendar style has `PART_HeaderButton` element.

You have to edit it's template.

1. Edit `Grid` set: `Background="Yellow"`.
2. Edit `ContentPresenter` set: `TextElement.Foreground="Red"`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLDWH.jpg)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this one.

Comment: can you give me an example? I can only change the whole background to "Yellow", but I can't get to the single element.

Comment: What do you mean by "single element"?

Comment: By single element I mean the button "Januar 2019". How can the color change here, e.g. red?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my previous custom style as follows:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomCalendar" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <Viewbox Height="300" Width="300" >
                        <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" 
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" FontStretch="Expanded">
                        </CalendarItem>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Active"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF777777" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DayStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="RegularDay"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Today">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground"/>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BlackoutDayStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDay"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="BlackoutDay">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Blackout"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" Fill="#FFAAAAAA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText" TextElement.Foreground="#FF333333" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,1,5,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="Blackout" Data="M8.1772461,11.029181 L10.433105,11.029181 L11.700684,12.801641 L12.973633,11.029181 L15.191895,11.029181 L12.844727,13.999395 L15.21875,17.060919 L12.962891,17.060919 L11.673828,15.256231 L10.352539,17.060919 L8.1396484,17.060919 L10.519043,14.042364 z" Fill="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="DayButtonFocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="Red" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="CalendarButtonStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CalendarButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarButton}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonFocusVisual">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonFocusVisual">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Active"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF777777" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DayStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="RegularDay"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Today">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground"/>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BlackoutDayStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDay"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="BlackoutDay">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Blackout"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#F6F9FB"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText" TextElement.Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,1,5,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="Blackout" Data="M8.1772461,11.029181 L10.433105,11.029181 L11.700684,12.801641 L12.973633,11.029181 L15.191895,11.029181 L12.844727,13.999395 L15.21875,17.060919 L12.962891,17.060919 L11.673828,15.256231 L10.352539,17.060919 L8.1396484,17.060919 L10.519043,14.042364 z" Fill="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonFocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="Red" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```